# String array token analysis using c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Two sample arrays:

```
string key[] = {"a|b", "a|c","a|d","b|c","b|d"};
int value[]={"2", "3","4","5","2"};
```

and these two arrays are connective `<a|b>->2 <a|c>->3 <a|d>->4 <b|c>->5 <b|d>->2`

every keys separated by `"|"` this token for the front_element and sencond_element

for example : `a|b` **a** is the front_element   **b** is the second_element

array could be a very large array and I want to find a way or algorithm
that could quick search the element

```
if(front_elemnet = "a"){ // find all of the front element with "a"
value_plus(); //plus the value 2+3+4
}
```

then check the next different front element

```
if(front_elemnet = "b"){ // find all of the front element with "b"
    value_plus(); //plus the value 5+2
    }
```

Comment: I have no idea what your question is. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Can you change the way the data is stored? Can you maintain a count for each letter as you add the data to the array? Or is it provided complete? Is the key always 1 letter?

Comment: Do you *need* to use arrays? Can't you use e.g. maps?

Comment: If you could convert your arrays in a map of maps like this: std::map< char, std::map<char,int> > you could easily get what you need.

Comment: we  get the <key,value> pair from the database ,a key align to a value

Comment: If map will get a good solution , how could I implement in this case

Comment: Have a map of letters to counts, and as you read values from the database, update the letter's count.

Comment: You don't need the second element in your example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int value_plus(const map<string, int>& myMap, string target)
{
    int res = 0;
    map<string, int>::const_iterator iter = myMap.begin();
    for(; iter!=myMap.end(); ++iter)
    {
        string key = iter->first;

        if(key.substr(0, 1) == target)
        {
            res += iter->second;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
int main() {
    string key[] = {"a|b", "a|c","a|d","b|c","b|d"};
    int value[] = {2, 3, 4, 5, 2};

    map<string, int> myMap;
    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(key)/sizeof(string); i++)
    {
        myMap.insert(std::pair<string, int>(key[i], value[i]));
    }

    cout<<"front_element = a "<<value_plus(myMap, "a")<<endl;
    cout<<"front_element = b "<<value_plus(myMap, "b")<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

You can use `map`, please refer: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/